# How to calculate weighted MTTR

Tags: summation, average

Can some one shed some light on how the the weighted MTTR (mean time to repair) is calculated. I understand that a weighted average is given by:
$$\frac{\sum w*MTTR}{\sum w}$$
where w is the weight.
But what exactly is the weight in which we need to find